# Are the algorithms a* and pathfinding a* the same?

Tags: path-finding, a-star

I also want to ask another thing, I'm making a game and inserting a pathfinding a* program into the game, but there is one side where the enemy is stuck in a dead end when they want to chase me. The enemy will come out from a dead end, if I change positions. Does the a* pathfinding algorithm fail or is that the result?

Comment: A* is greedy but will always find a path if one exists.

Comment: oh really ? why ?

Comment: What do you mean why? That is just one of the properties of the A* search algorithm. ["__A* is guaranteed to return a least-cost path from start to goal__"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)